# How can i receive 1 argument with the python library parser and use just the argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, terminal

I'm doing a command line application to verify if a website is active, and i want to receive one argument, but the parser needs receive an argument and a valor for this argument, So my question is: How can i use just 1 argument ?
This is my code:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    import requests
    import datetime
    from time import sleep
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('u',  help="Unique verification")
    parser.add_argument('c', help="Continuos verification")
    parser.add_argument('s', help="Check and save to file")
    parser.add_argument('d', help="Documentation")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(parser.parse_args)
```

My function main receives a char, how can i use a  char via command line?

Comment: You either want *one* argument, with an explicit list of valid values (`add_argument('foo', choices=['u', 'c', 's', 'd'])`), or you want to define 4 separate subparsers, each triggered by  one of `u`, `c`, `s`, or `d` as the first argument.

Comment: I want to call the program in terminal like this:
`python3 verify.py -u`
or `python3 verify.py -c`
and  gave this argument for my main function

Comment: where i need to use this??

Comment: Sorry, hit return by accident in the middle of the comment, then decided what I was about to type should be an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently creating mandatory *positional* arguments, so that a call like

```
python3 verify.py foo bar baz bye
```

would result in

```
args.u == 'foo'
args.c == 'bar'
args.s == 'baz'
args.d == 'bye'
```

You want to define four *options*, using the `store_true` action so that providing the option will set a flag from its default `False` value to `True`.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-u', action='store_true', help="Unique verification")
parser.add_argument('-c', action='store_true', help="Continuos verification")
parser.add_argument('-s', action='store_true', help="Check and save to file")
parser.add_argument('-d', action='store_true', help="Documentation")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now a call like

```
python3 verify.py -u -s
```

would result in

```
args.u == True
args.c == False
args.s == True
args.d == False
```

If you want to further restrict the user to exactly *one* of the four options, use a mutual-exclusion group.

```
# Same as above, calling group.add_argument, not parser.add_argument
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-u', action='store_true', help="Unique verification")
group.add_argument('-c', action='store_true', help="Continuos verification")
group.add_argument('-s', action='store_true', help="Check and save to file")
group.add_argument('-d', action='store_true', help="Documentation")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: If i use this?
```   
parser.add_argument('u', action='u',  help="Unique verification")
    parser.add_argument('c', action='c', help="Continuos verification")
    parser.add_argument('s', action='s', help="Check and save to file")
    parser.add_argument('d', action='d', help="Documentation")```

Comment: No, the `action` argument is either a subclass of `argparse.Action` or a string that is registered to reference such a class. And unless you are defining [subcommands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands), you don't want to use positional arguments.